# Two object updating each other somehow

Tags: java, object

I have an object called savingsAccount, when I create two objects of this type on my main I can set the users initial account balance. When I create my first object initial value of 3000 is set, when I create my second object with initial value of 2000 is set for both my first and second object

First I thought it was related to public methods and classes, but I set them all to either private, protected etc and the problem still persists.

this is my object:

```
public class SavingsAccount {
private static double annualInterestRate = 0;
private static double savingsBalance = 0;
private static double monthlyInterest = 0;


SavingsAccount(double savingsBalance){
    this.savingsBalance = savingsBalance;
}

void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate){
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;

}


private static void updateSavingsBalance(){
    savingsBalance = savingsBalance + monthlyInterest;
}

double getSavingsBalance(){
    return savingsBalance;
}

}
```

this is my Driver:

```
    SavingsAccount saver1 = new SavingsAccount(3000.00);
    System.out.println("User 1 balance: " + saver1.getSavingsBalance()); // 3000

    SavingsAccount saver2 = new SavingsAccount(2000.00);
    System.out.println("User 2 balance: " + saver2.getSavingsBalance()); // 2000

    //2000 for both now
    System.out.println("User 1 balance: " + saver1.getSavingsBalance());
    System.out.println("User 2 balance: " + saver2.getSavingsBalance());
```

Comment: Try making savingsBalance not static     https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/what-is-the-static-keyword-in-java/

Comment: Why are you using static instance variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `static` variables, as opposed to non-static (instance) variables.

There is only a single incarnation of each static variable - so in your case, no matter how many `SavingsAccount` objects you create, they are all sharing the same `savingsBalance` data.  As such, when you (think you are) change one of the `SavingAccount`'s `savingsBalance`, you are changing it for all of them